# How to submit data without GET and POST Method.?

Tags: php, javascript, client-side, server-side

by using post method ,i cant see what are the values passed in url, is there a way other than GET to achieve this, i heard there is a way by using coding in scripts. anybody have idea on this? Thanks in Advance..

Comment: well there is something in codeigniter called segments a good way to submit data without post and get

Comment: am not sure what your question is

Answer (score 3):

> by using post method ,i cant see what are the values passed in url

Yes, you can. No values are passed in the URL and you can see all zero of them! ;)

More seriously, you can see what data is passed in the body by using the network tab of your browser's debug tools or by using a proxy server such as Charles Proxy.

You shouldn't consider changing the HTTP method for data inspection. It just means that you either end up using an inappropriate method in production, or that you risk things breaking when you change back to the correct method.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can try to use javascript(jquery, etc..) to catch all values from your control box in the form, then render as the url link on the view.